# Connection Reset on driver.quit()

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, driver, connection-reset

I'm getting the following error trying to perform in Java-Selenium  `driver.quit()`

I have the following chrome version: 111.0.5563.65 and the last chrome driver version: 111.0.5563.64

```
Mar 14, 2023 2:00:24 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:259)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Can somebody help me?

I tried to downgrade the selenium version from 4.8.1 to 4.8.0 but the error still occurs

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project always after component up/downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

1. refer this: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

```js
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-orgins=*");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options); 
driver.get("google"); 
driver.quit();

//refer this website : https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
```